# R counter, counting frequency in a table

Tags: r, timer, counter, cumulative-frequency

I have following data set

```
        id      year
2      20332           2005
3       6383           2005
14     20332           2006
15      6806           2006
16     23100           2006
```

I would like to have an additional column, which counts the number of years the id variable is already available:

```
        id      year        Counter
2      20332           2005     1
3       6383           2005     1
14     20332           2006     2
15      6806           2006     1
16     23100           2006     1
```

The dataset is currently not sorted according to the year. I thought about mutate rather than a function.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try `df1$Counter <- with(df1, ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add column with order counts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470413/add-column-with-order-counts) Or [R: assign incremental numbers to rows containing a same label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663752/r-assign-incremental-numbers-to-rows-containing-a-same-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$Counter <- with(df1, ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))
```